# Rules for lookup of operators in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

[N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), "Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++," gives the following example in clause 13.3.1.2, p. 10:

```
struct A { };
void operator + (A, A);
struct B {
  void operator + (B);
  void f ();
};
A a;
void B::f() {
  operator+ (a,a);   // error: global operator hidden by member
  a + a;             // OK: calls global operator+
}
```

However, this is just a note:

> Note: The lookup rules for operators in expressions are different than the lookup rules for operator function names in a function call, as shown in the following example:

My question is where in the standard does it say that this is what has to happen as opposed to just having the note with an example?

As far as I can tell, according to clause 13.3.1.2, p. 2, operator expressions are converted to operator function calls. So why and how should there be a difference in the example above?

### Edit:

After looking into the problem, I think that I may have overlooked p. 3 and p.6 in the same clause that together state that global candidates and member candidates are considered equally when looking up operators (thus lookup rules are different as the note says). However, my inquiry into this subject was stemmed by this example that compiles in the same way with GCC 4.8 and Clang:

```
struct X {};  struct Y {};

void operator+(X, X) { }
void operator+(X, Y) { }

void test() {
  void operator+(X, X);
  X x; Y y;

  x + x;  // OK
  x + y;  // OK

  operator+(x, y);  // error
  operator+(x, x);  // OK
}
```

Why is there shadowing by the block scope declaration when the operator function is called directly but not when it is called by operator expression?

Here are the errors from GCC:

```
operators-main-ss.cpp: In function ‘void test()’:
operators-main-ss.cpp:13:17: error: could not convert ‘y’ from ‘Y’ to ‘X’
   operator+(x, y);  // error
                 ^
```

And here from Clang:

```
operators-main-ss.cpp:13:16: error: no viable conversion from 'Y' to 'X'
  operator+(x, y);  // error
               ^
operators-main-ss.cpp:1:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no
      known conversion from 'Y' to 'const X &' for 1st argument;
struct X {};  struct Y {};
       ^
operators-main-ss.cpp:7:22: note: passing argument to parameter here
  void operator+(X, X);
                     ^
```

Are the compilers correct to have the block declaration shadow the global name in one case but not the other?

Comment: It's like you just set out to give me a headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the compilers correct to have the block declaration shadow the
>   global name in one case but not the other?

I have come to the conclusion that both compilers are wrong. I believe `x + y;` should also fail. 13.3.1.2p3 states it clearly:

> The set of non-member candidates is the result of the unqualified
>   lookup of operator@ in the context of the expression according to the
>   usual rules for name lookup in unqualified function calls (3.4.2)
>   except that all member functions are ignored.

As a result, there should be no difference between `x + y;` and `operator+(x, y);` in your example. [Commeau online](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) produces the following errors with the code:

```
"ComeauTest.c", line 11: error: no operator "+" matches these operands
            operand types are: X + Y
    x + y;  // OK
      ^
"ComeauTest.c", line 13: error: no suitable user-defined conversion from "Y"
 to "X"
          exists
    operator+(x, y);  // error
```

Comment: That's strange. I tried the Intel compiler, which also uses the EDG frontend, and I got no errors at all. I am utterly confused now. BTW, downloading the Intel compiler is a pain.

Comment: @MarcinZalewski: I just tested the code with MSVC2012. The code compiles, but intellisense gives the same errors as commeau (very strange).

Comment: That is because, according to EDG group's page, MSVC uses the EDG frontend for intellisense but not for the actual compilation. Also it seems that MSVC must be using a different version of EDG frontend than the newest Intel compiler.

Comment: @MarcinZalewski:Thanks, I didn't know that. I tried looking up the EDG version used, but couldn't find any recent info.

Comment: So which frontend do we trust now? :) I am inclined to go with the newest version of EDG since they always are quite pedantic on standard compliance, but I don't see where in the standard does it say that they do the right thing. For Clang, [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.clang.devel/22559) discussion seems to be related. If this has not changed until now, Clang seems to be ill-equipped to deal with this issue.

Comment: I have received a word from some compiler writers that your analysis is indeed correct and that the Commeau compiler does the right thing.

Answer (score 4):

Your original question:

Your conclusion is correct.

`operator+(a, a);` is a simple function call so the compiler searches for potential matches in the standard order, finds the member function and never looks any further. The member function doesn't match and the expression is ill formed.

`a + a;` uses a slightly different set of rules as defined in 13.3.1.2 p3. First a set of possible overloads is produced from `A::operator+(a)`. Then a list of possible overloads is produced from a standard unqualified lookup but member functions are ignored. A list of builtin operators is then created. These 3 lists are then used to decide the best match. Normally, unqualified lookup would stop after the first step if it found something which is why this works where it would normally fail.

Question part 2:

In theory this should be the same. No member functions involved and builtin operators are irrelevant so they should all result in a standard unqualified lookup. I can't find anything in the standard to suggest they should be in any way different. I don't see much mention of block scope function declarations in the standard aside from "they exist". They are mostly just a relic of C after all. I also don't see any specific rules in the standard that state one way or the other about whether this should work or not. The standard does suggest very strongly that `x + y` and `operator+(x, y)` should either both work or both fail since they both use the same method for name lookup.

I also have yet to find a valid use case for nested function declarations.

Comment: I did not know much about block-scope declarations either until I started looking into this problem. It seems that one can use them to avoid pollution of global namespace, to turn off ADL, and to explicitly select which functions should be called at a given block. Otherwise, block-scope declarations seem to act the same as non-block-scope ones. Of course, block-scope-definitions are not allowed. I would not advocate block-scope declarations, but those are the possible scenarios that I could come up with and that do not seem achievable using other means.

Comment: @Marcin Zalewski I am not sure how they avoid namespace pollution since the definition (and presumably linkage) would still be outside the function and a qualified name, casting or redirection would solve the selection issue so I still don't see a need for them. That said, I pride myself myself on knowing pretty much all the dark corners so I _will_ be obsessing over this. Will update the answer if/when I find out more.

Comment: The linkage does not need to be from the same file. It's similar to using directives. You can put one outside a block scope, but if you only need it for one block scope, you can just put it directly in there. If you use a qualified name, you are selecting only **one** function, but with block-scope declarations you can select more and perform overload resolution on this selection. Again, I have not actually seen much of such uses, but these uses are the only ones I could come up with.

Comment: But n that case a using directive would work or redirection. I.e. Put a new function in an independant namespace and import what you want. Casting the arguments to more appropriate types would also change the selected function without restricting to one function. I guess it's a little like C style casts. It's just a backwards compatibility feature which happens to provide another way of doing some of the same things.

Comment: Perhaps you are correct. Maybe the only reason for block-scope declarations is compatibility with C. I would really like to know if this was the only motivation behind this feature, and if it would be desirable to remove it were it not for compatibility.

Comment: Note that the link about nested functions says: `extension in GNU C, but are not supported by GNU C++` Also, 3.4.2p3 I believe mentions the rule about block-scope declarations: `Let X be the lookup set produced by unqualified lookup (3.4.1) and let Y be the lookup set produced by
argument dependent lookup (defined as follows). If X contains a block-scope function declaration that is not a using-declaration then Y is empty`

Comment: @JesseGood You are indeed right about the link. On the second point though the function call and the operator both boil down to a same lookup (with the exception of member functions which is irrelevant here) so i don't see how they should come to different results.

Comment: @John5342: Right, I agree with you. I believe both compilers are wrong (I mentioned this in my answer). I just wanted to point out where the standard mentions `block-scope function declarations`.

Comment: @JesseGood Fair enough. Thanks. I have removed the wrong info about nested functions now.

Comment: BTW, I have not marked either of your answers as an accepted answer yet because the different compilers give at least 3 different answers (see the comments on @JesseGood's answer). I am especially troubled by the change of the behavior between EDG frontends. The new frontend either does the right thing, or it introduces a bug comparing to what the old frontend did in the Commeau compiler. Perhaps there is still some other part of the standard that we are all missing. Or the EDG people got it wrong. Hopefully we can gat this cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

concerning your question part 2

here is a quote from standard c++11 concerning ADL $3.4.2:

> Let X be the lookup set produced by unqualified lookup (3.4.1) and let Y be the lookup set produced by argument dependent lookup (defined as follows). If X contains
>
> - a declaration of a class member, or
> - a block-scope function declaration that is not a using-declaration, or
> - a declaration that is neither a function or a function template
>
> then Y is empty.
>
> ...

it seems, that answers your question