# Difference between a+b and operator+(a,b)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer

Consider the following program:

```
#include<functional>

typedef std::function< int( int ) > F;

F operator+( F, F )
{
    return F();
}

int f( int x ) { return x; }

int main()
{
    operator+(f,f); // ok
    f+f; // error: invalid operands to binary expression
}
```

Why does the last line `f+f;` not compile? Why is it not identical to `operator+(f,f);`? A reference to the standard would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869150/rules-for-lookup-of-operators-in-c11 ?

Comment: @Cubbi I don't think that's a duplicate, it's about *overloaded* member and block scope operators.

Comment: well that answer brought up the lookup rules (which are quite different for `a+b` vs. `operator+(a,b)`), so it would answer the title of your question.. but yes, in this case, there's a shortcut in the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `f` is a built-in type. Operations on objects of built-in types never consider user-define operators. Calling `operator+(f, f)` explicitly force two conversions which will not happen unless they are forced. The relevant clause is 13.3.1.2 [over.match.oper] paragraph 1:

> If no operand of an operator in an expression has a type that is a class or an enumeration, the operator is assumed to be a built-in operator and interpreted according to Clause 5. ...

Comment: Thanks! I think that also explains *why*: Compatibility with C. A valid expression from C like `f+f` should yield the same result. Something like `operator+(f,f)` doesn't exist in C, hence it's OK to treat it like a C++ function call. Correct?